# How to use variable in select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I'm trying to use the logic for using SSIS

```
select top 2 * from table
```

How can I replace 2 with variable name and make it customize?

**Update**

I tried using expression and i received the following error:

[image]

Comment: @IsaacVidrine the question is not SSIS related, how it can be a duplicate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065855/use-variables-in-ssis-select-and-from-clause

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming that the variable that contains the number of top rows is named `@[User::TopCount]`*

Create a variable of type string (example: `@[User::strQuery]`), set its property `EvaluateAsExpression` to `True`. And assign the following expression:

```
"SELECT TOP " + (DT_WSTR,10)@[User::TopCount] + " * FROM table"
```

Inside the data flow task add an OLEDB Source and set the Access mode to SQL Command from variable and use `@[User:strQuery` variable as source.

Comment: @TirathSingh can you provide the expression used?

Comment: @TirathSingh check the following link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4564/ssis-variable-and-expression-example--part-1/ follow the `SSIS Expression for Variables` section

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @numrows int = 5

select top (@numrows) * from MyTable
```